# Linear Interpolation Between two Frames in OpenGl3 and above

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I have two frames (i.e. two meshes composed of an equal number of vertices) and I am attempting to write a vertex shader that linearly interpolates to morph frame 1 into frame 2. I was reading through a tutorial that showed how to do this in an older version OpenGL. The algorithm is basically:

```
GLBegin
 For each vertex in frame 1
  Send equivalent vertex to uniform variable in vertex shader from frame 2
  Send vertex from frame 1 to vertex shader
  (shader uses mix() to linearly interpolate between the two XYZ values)
GLEnd
```

But this isn't how things are done in OpenGL3+. Can someone help me think of an algorithm where I could still use mix() in the vertex shader to create a morph between two meshes/frames?

Comment: OpenGL 3+ I believe is backward compatible with OpenGL older versions, therefore, why don't you implement it as the example shows.  If it works, then it is compatible with more systems anyway!!!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to use two sets of position attributes and a uniform for the blend factor between 0 and 1, and then just mix between them using the blend factor via GLSL's `mix` function. When you completely reach 1.0, you can switch back to factor 0, but use the second mesh now as the first set by just updating the vertex attrib pointers.

Comment: This is just the algorithm I'm describing above. I'm wondering about how to implement this in OpenGL3+ where you have to deal with vertex buffers instead of setting the state with GlBegin and End.

Comment: @CollinSchupman: and I actually told you how to do it. Use two vertex attributes, that is all that is needed there